# How to disable _source field using spring data elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

In elastic search, I can disable the _source field like :-

```
  PUT tweets
    {
      "mappings": {
        "tweet": {
          "_source": {
            "enabled": false
          }
        }
      }}
```

How to achieve this using spring data-elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can put this mapping by:-

1) hard coded   2) can be read from a properties file  3) build it using Xcontentbuilder

We can use the `ElasticsearchTemplate` class provided by spring data to do this like :-

```
           if (!elasticsearchTemplate.indexExists(esIndex)) {
                elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(esIndex);
                elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(esIndex, esType,mappingObject);
             }
```

This mappingObject is a string read from properties file.
It can be like this :-

### es-configs.properties

```
mapping={"_source": {"includes": [ "id","name","marks","grade"],"excludes": ["contact_info","phone_num"]}}
```

In this case we are excluding fields *contact_info* and *phone_num*. So those fields won't be included in `_source` of index. 
This is the case when we use spring data elasticsearch.
If you are not using spring data then we can do the same with Xcontentbuilder.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example? Thanks.

Comment: @AlessandroC : Hi,I've edited the question. Comment here if you need any help! cheers :)

Comment: @Sachin, can we add or remove fields from es-configs.properties as per requirement? we intend to use spring data elastic search and in some request we want to return all fields and in other we want to return only few fields, is this possible in spring data?

Comment: I think this would help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237084/only-return-specific-fields-in-elastic-search-native-query-java-api